# Eclipse won't detect my phone anymore (Win 10)

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-10, adb, samsung-galaxy

Please bear with me, I know there are a lot of threads about the same problem but I've tried everything suggested in them to fix it and nothing has worked so far.

I used to use an S7 (Android 7) on my private Win 7 PC and set up a Win 10 workstation a couple of weeks ago that I've been using since. Since then, every time I connected the phone to the PC, it displayed a message on the phone about giving permission to use the MTP connection (Which it only did once on my Win 7 PC) and then debugging was working just fine.

Yesterday the phone didn't show that message and Eclipse also didn't detect it (it didn't show up in the "Devices" tab), I had to restart the PC to get it to work again (restarting ADB,.. didn't work). Today even restarting the PC didn't help.

What I've tried so far:

- Restart the S7
- Restart the PC
- Kill and restart ADB (through Eclipse and command line - said "daemon not running; starting now at tcp:xxxx", then "daemon started successfully" every time)
- Disable and re-enable Developer Mode
- Disable and re-enable USB-Debugging
- Change connection mode to PTP and back to MTP
- Set to "always prompt to pick device" instead of "automatic" in Eclipse (Run - Run Configurations - Target) - it's now back on "automatic"
- Different USB port
- Different USB cable
- I installed the Google USB driver through the SDK Manager when I started using Win 10 but Eclipse stopped detecting the S7 after restarting the PC, so I uninstalled it again and have been using the driver Win 10 found since then (and, like I said, everything has been working fine until yesterday)
- Install Kies (it told me to connect a phone, even though the S7 was connected)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem is: It's Windows 10 downloading updates in the background!

Why I think it's the updates:

- Yesterday, when the PC had stopped detecting the phone, I restarted it, which took longer than usual because it had to install a couple of updates.
- Today, after writing the first post and installing Kies, I did another restart and it installed updates again - afterwards it worked fine again.
- I just came back from my lunch break (I disconnected the phone before I left) and the "MTP permission" message didn't pop up again and Eclipse also didn't find the S7 again, so I restarted the PC: This time it didn't say "updating" but again it did take longer than a normal restart and it displayed a spinning circle, which it usually does when it's still reconfiguring stuff after installing updates.

Comment: It's weird, today it took a restart to get the PC to see the phone (it didn't even see it in the explorer, even though the S7 was charging) but it didn't install any updates this time. I still have to do some more testing but it's possible that it's not the actual downloading of updates that causes the problem but even looking for them.

Comment: In the last couple of days it happened again twice: One time it didn't say anything about updates but rebooting the PC took longer than usual, the other time Win 10 did install updates again. Honestly, I don't know what exactly could be causing this because not only does Eclipse not see the phone but there's also no entry in the Windows Explorer for it (not sure if it's charging).